# Can we set live django project on local machine

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to setup live django project on local machine for practice. There are many ways to set php projects on local machine, same as is there any way for django.

Comment: see the [tutorial on he official website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: No like we do the codeigniter project migration from live to local for beginners to understand the project , can we do it for django.

Comment: Basically, no. If it's hosted on Heroku, then yes, but that's because Heroku created custom scripts and cli. But there exists no uniform way to do this. You'll have to use your brain and knowledge of [python packaging](https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the development server locally you can use this command.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I want to know can we migrate django project from live server to local machine

Comment: Yes, you can, just copy the project to your local machine and use this command to run the local development server.